# Warring: Unused variable: rider ( Gmake, g++ , freebsd )

Tags: c++

This is the error message:

```
 File.cpp:130: warning: unused variable 'file'
```

And here is the code:

I do not want to delete the variable rider that is unused.

I want to use but do not know where I was wrong.

My default compiler is GCC , on freebsd 9.2

Comment: `File.cpp:901: warning: unused variable 'rider'` Could you at least post the code from this particular line? Did you actually don't
 use `rider` within this scope, but declare it?

Comment: What is the code to declare this variable? rider. 
I tried a few times to say but nothing compilation error. 

Can you give me the correct syntax.

Comment: _@irinel-iovan_ Could you please narrow this wall of code to the relevant stuff?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatively as from the other answers, if you insist having the variable declared, you can just cast it to `void` avoiding the warning message:

```
    LPCHARACTER rider = GetRider();
    (void)rider; // Makes thé compiler look aside 'unused variable'
 // ^^^^^^
```

If you later decide, to use the variable, the above mentioned statement doesn't do any harm.

I found this particularly useful, for fixing unused function parameter warnings.

Comment: Thank you.  I have only seen this idea one time before. I think I now grok it.

Answer (score 1):

You have a statement as below:

```
LPCHARACTER rider = GetRider();
```

The variable rider has not been used after this line, it appears. 
If you indeed don't require ro use, then either ignore the warning, or write without storing return value from GetRider():

```
GetRider();
```

Better to find out that you really don;t need to use rider.
Your call.

Answer (score 1):

This is the line causing the warning:

```
LPCHARACTER rider = GetRider();
```

You never use this variable. That's why you get a "unused variable" warning. If you don't need it,just remove that line.

Comment: What if `GetRider()` has required side-effects?

Comment: @NeilKirk , I don't know what is in `GetRider()` but if it needs to be called, let the OP do it.